# Auto increment column value by 3 columns in copying across a row

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel 2 worksheet workbook - 'Dairy' and 'Production'
Formula in 'Production' E10 is 'Dairy'!I33
I want the Formula in 'Production' E11 to be 'Dairy'!L33   (an increment of 3 columns, but same row.)
I cannot use Alt EIR, because it only increments the cell value (I33) by one column (to J33).
What formula can I use to increase the I33 by 3 columns to L33, then in the next cell/E11 increase the L33 to O33, and so on?

```
EXAMPLE -
Production cell  number  E10     E11     E12    E13
Production cell value   D!I33    D!L33  D!O33  D!R33
```

thank you,
Mike

Comment: @jainashish & user11121185 -OH, my - I goofed in providing the information. The target cells need to move across columns, not down rows. Target cells:  E10 = D!I33, F10=D!L33, G10= D!O33, H10=D!R33, I10=D!U33, ETC.  As I move across the Target columns 1 at a time, the target cell increments the source cell by 3 columns. Sorry, I cannot paste examples from the workbook in this comment window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDEX typically uses less calculation cycles than OFFSET and this benefit increases the more formulas you have.

```
=INDEX(Dairy!33:33, 1, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*3+9)
```

Put that under E10 and drag right (and down if needed).

If E10 is actually the cell you want the formula and you are going to drag it down then use this in E10 and drag down.

```
=INDEX(Dairy!$33:$33, 1, (ROW(1:1)-1)*3+9)
```

Comment: This INDEX works going across columns and solves my formula issue.  I just had to adjust for the starting column I, so the formula is - INDEX (Dairy!33:33,1,(COLUMN(I:I)-9*3+9)   THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Offset formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) which returns a reference to a range that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells. The reference that is returned can be a single cell or a range of cells. You can specify the number of rows and the number of columns to be returned.

**Syntax:**

```
 =OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

**Solution**:

```
Cell E10 Formula : =OFFSET(Dairy!I$33,0,0,1,1)
Cell E11 Formula : =OFFSET(Dairy!I$33,0,3,1,1)
Cell E12 Formula : =OFFSET(Dairy!I$33,0,6,1,1)
```

and so on....

To make it completely dynamic, link the third argument to the current row. For e.g.

```
Cell E10 Formula : =OFFSET(Dairy!I$33,0,MOD(ROW(A10),10)*3,1,1)
```